What's the default access of private class members in swift?
Consider the following quote from swift docs:

The access control level of a type also affects the default access level of that type’s members (its properties, methods, initializers, and subscripts). If you define a type’s access level as private or file private, the default access level of its members will also be private or file private.

Problem:
Keeping the above quote in mind, the "somePrivateMethod" in the following example code example (also taken from swift docs) should be private:
private class SomePrivateClass {  // explicitly private class
   func somePrivateMethod() {}   // implicitly private class member
}

But when I tried to access somePrivateMethod outside the SomePrivateClass but in the same file, the method is accessible.
SomePrivateClass().somePrivateMethod() // why is it accessible?

Question:
Is the quote from the documentation incorrect or am I missing something?
Swift version: 5.9.2

How are you able to say SomePrivateClass() in the first place, seeing as it is private? You must be saying it in the same file as SomePrivateClass's declaration. Show us the real code, in context please.

@matt I have already mentioned in the question that SomePrivateClass().somePrivateMethod() is executed in the same swift file that contains the declaration of SomePrivateClass.

Yes; the documentation here is misleading. The behavior is correct and expected according to the rules (as Daniel T covers), but I recommend opening a documentation bug at bugs.swift.org about the example. The wording in the paragraph is a misleading, but the comment in the example is clearly wrong and should be fixed.

Remember... when you make a type private, it is accessible throughout the scope of the file. So:
private class SomeClass { }
private func somePrivateMethod() {}

Both the class and the function have the same access level. They both accessible within the file they are declared in.
When you do:
private class SomePrivateClass {  // explicitly private class
   func somePrivateMethod() {}   // implicitly private class member
}

The class and the function both have the same access level. Exactly as my former example...

But that's not what the documentation states. One would expect a private class member to not be accessible outside that class, which is what happens if you explicitly mark the somePrivateMethod as private. But the question is about the default access level of type's members when the type itself is marked as private. According to the docs, the type's members are implicitly private but that doesn't seems to be the case.

You cannot access the method anywhere outside of where you can access the class. The method obviously does not have internal level, and it has the same access level as a private function defined at the same level as the class, so what would you call it if not private?

I understand your point but there is a difference between private method at the top level of a swift file and a private method inside a class. Private method, or any private member of a class, shouldn't be accessible outside its class. Explicitly marking the somePrivateMethod as private makes it inaccessible outside the class, and this is what I expected without explicitly marking somePrivateMethod as private because the docs state that the default access of type's members is private if the type itself is private.

Clearly the default access level of members of a private type is not private. It seems to be fileprivate.

Clearly, the private function and the private class are both accessible throughout the file. Maybe you just don't understand what private means in this context...

"the private function and the private class are both accessible throughout the file" - yes, and this is why I asked the question. If you mark the somePrivateMethod as private, it won't be accessible outside the class, and this is my understanding of a private type member.
